# How to upload zip/rar or any compressed file using PHP

Tags: php

this is just a simple. I created a form in php to upload a zip/rar or any compressed file only and send to my server. This was send successfully but, this is my problem: I can't open the zip/rar or any compressed file and it shows a message "Access is denied". Here is my code.

```
$file=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$allowedTypes = array('application/zip', 'application/x-rar-compressed', 'application/octet-stream');

if ($_FILES["file"]["type"]!="")
{
    if (in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], $allowedTypes))
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            $alert= "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"];
        }
        else
        {
            if (file_exists("../uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
            {
                $alert= $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                //I renamed the file into FILENAME
                $newfilename = 'FILENAME.'.pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                //file permission
                mkdir($newfilename , 0777, true);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../uploads/".$newfilename);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                $alert = "Error in Uploading the File.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How or what should I do?

Comment: Which line is causing the error? What OS is your PHP code running on and what filesystem permissions does it have? It's possible the user-account that the PHP process is running under lacks permission to call `chmod` or create directories.

Comment: there's no error because the zip/rar was send successfully to server but i can't extract. OS is Win10 and i use 0777 for permission